# Bypass password authentication for a database once a user is logged in as user on Unix?

Tags: java, oracle, unix, jdbc

I have written applications in Java which connect to the database by taking the username and password for the database which is set in the environment variables. So the database username and password are stored as clear text in a file on the server.

Here is the code which creates the connection string:

```
if (dataBase.equals("oracle"))
{
    url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@";
    url = url + getParameter("Database IP", "setup.ini");           // ip
    url = url + ":" + getParameter("Database Port", "setup.ini");   //port
    String envVarValue = System.getenv("DBNAME");

    // Environment variable has value DBNAME = 

    String a[] = envVarValue.split("@");
    url = url + ":" + getParameter("SID", "setup.ini");
    String b[] = a[0].split("/");
    userName = b[0]; //User name
    password = b[1]; //Password
}
```

Now I want my application to be able to connect to the database by the Unix user who would be running this application on the server without the need to get the password for the database user in the code.

Please tell me if this is possible and how if yes?

Comment: What system user is this application running as?

Comment: Take a look at [OS authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authentication.htm#i1007520)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this link on how to configure a user account for OS authentication in Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/clntsec.htm#CIHCBCBC

You can read the current OS user running your java program by calling `System.getProperty("user.name")`. When creating connection through JDBC, you may have to append this value to the prefix `OS_AUTHENT_PREFIX` you created as shown in the link above.

Comment: Can I use JDBC thin driver for OS authentication in Oracle 10g?

Comment: I checked the link that you posted. It was mentioned there to make some changes in the **t_init1.ora** file. I searched and found no such file on my server. WHat is this file and how to make the changes that are mentioned in that link?

Comment: I was able to implement OS authentication using the above solution on a java application build on version 1.6
I want to know that can we implement the same in version 1.4 ?
I had to use ojdbc5.jar instead of classes12.jar to implement this. But I read somewhere that classes12.jar doesn't support OS authentication. Can you please confirm the same and if its true can you give me an alternative?